# How to trace a Method in a spring aop?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I want to log a message in the format MethodName invoked at date-time in the console whenever the method successfully completes.

I have defined a custom performance intwerceptor by extending the AbstarctMonitoringInterceptor. Then I am confused what to do next? I mean how to include it in xml or in my aspect class, so that it executes?

Here is my code:

```
    public class MyPerformanceMonitorInterceptor extends AbstractMonitoringInterceptor {

public MyPerformanceMonitorInterceptor() {
}

public MyPerformanceMonitorInterceptor(boolean useDynamicLogger) {
        setUseDynamicLogger(useDynamicLogger);
}

@Override
protected Object invokeUnderTrace(MethodInvocation mi, Log log) throws Throwable {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name = createInvocationTraceName(mi);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("Method " + name + " execution started at:" + new Date());
    try {
        return mi.proceed();
    }
    finally {
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time = end - start;
        log.info("Method "+name+" execution lasted:"+time+" ms");
        log.info("Method "+name+" execution ended at:"+new Date());
        }          
}
```

[image: Project Structure]

Logging is my aspect class. How to add this custom to my aspect class and get the invocation time?

Comment: Why write it yourself... Spring already has the `PerformanceMonitorInterceptor` which does all this for you ... Or if you really want to go loose you could use the `CustomizableTraceInterceptor` instead.

Comment: hi i have added the custom interceptor . Now how to add this and get the time ??

Comment: You would need to modify the message. But in your sample you already have the time the `start` is the date and time at which your method was executed. Just format it to a `Date` or `DateTime` and print it. Also your new interceptor already does print the date and time. So not sure what you are asking now.

Comment: hi i need to know how to use this in my aspect  i have only created it then i have to use it with the pointcut and advice right..